# For each vector space of functions of one real variable, represent the derivative transformation with respect to B,B.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

{acosx +bsinx | a,b ∈ R}, B = < cosx, sinx  >

My work is the following:

{{1},{0}} h-> cos x

{{0},{1}} h-> sin x

RepB(cos x) = {{1},{0}}
since cos x = Acosx +Bsinx

RepB(sin x) = {{0},{1}}

My solution: {{1,0},{0,1}}, but the actual solution is {{0,1},{-1,0}}. Can someone help me and tell me what I did wrong. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your reasoning. Where is the derivative transformation in your solution? It seems you have represented elements of the basis $B$ in the basis $B$ (and obviously got identity matrix). You should represent values of the transformation on the basis - that is, *derivatives* of basis elements.

Answer (score 0):

Denote by $\;D\;$ the derivative map:

$$\begin{align*}D(\cos x)&=-\sin x=\color{red}0\cdot \cos x+\color{red}{(-1)}\sin x\\
D(\sin x)&=\;\;\cos x=\color{red}1\cdot\cos x+\color{red}0\sin x\end{align*}$$

and since the matrix for $\;D\;$ is the transpose of the above system's coefficients we get

$$\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\\!\!-1&0\end{pmatrix}$$